# how to convert text file into one list

Tags: python

I have a text file which has some lines:

```
someone can tell/figure
a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil
accounts for (someone or something)
```

I'm making it as one list but it's returning a list for each line

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    text = [line.split('\n') for line in f]
    print(text)

Output:
[['someone can tell/figure', ''], ['a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil', ''], ['accounts for (someone or something)', '']]
```

I want something like this

```
['someone can tell/figure', 'a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil', "accounts for (someone's or something)"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: use `strip`, not `split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `strip` and `readlines` methods for this:

```
someone can tell/figure
a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil
accounts for (someone or something)
```

(make sure to open the file correctly)

```
with open('words.txt', "r") as f:
    text = [line.strip() for line in f] #or rstrip()
print(text)
```

output:

```
['someone can tell/figure', 'a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil', 'accounts for (someone or something)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without the split,

```py
text = []
with open('input.file') as f:
    for line in f:
        text.append(line.strip('\n'))
    print(text)
```

Comment: @User1010, I would recommend you to use `rstrip()` instead

Comment: the `"\n"` in`strip("\n")` is redundant

Comment: @Ironkey, no it's not.

Comment: yes it is for the application of this question... you can simply use `.strip()`, or as you said, `rstrip()`

Comment: @Ironkey, no you shouldn't do that, cause it will clear all whitespace chars both on line start and line end.

Comment: in this case, he might want to do that, and despite that, there is no whitespace in the given example

Comment: OP makes no claim how leading or trailing whitespace should be handled one way or the other. `strip` and `rstrip` with or without "\n" all satisfy the requirements.

Comment: ^ so you would want the most simplistic code in this case

Comment: @Ironkey, [Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2).

Comment: @Ironkey - I have no idea what you mean by "simplistic". We don't know which form is best for OP.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# open the text file using the 'r' (read) mode.
file = open(file = 'text_file_1.txt', mode='r')

# print the contents, using the split method, splitting at a new lines.
print(file.read().split('\n'))

# close file after the process/tasks are complete.
file.close()

# output:
['someone can tell/figure', 'a/the squeaky wheel gets the grease/oil', 'accounts for (someone or something)']
```

Comment: There's `spitlines()`.